# using COALESCE in mysql to get the shipping charges

Tags: mysql, coalesce

Need to create a sql view for calculating the commission & shipping charges. Shipping charges per item but they are charged on order id level which can have multiple order items Please have a look at the image attached. Pls note as shipping charges are at order id level.And not at order item id level. Order item id column is blank for shipping charges row.So in order to get the Shipping charges we would need to divide by no of items in the order

order item id is no of items in that order, Each order id can have one or multiple order item id's
[image of view required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46cRr.png)

[Sql fiddle schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aec43)

```
SELECT main.order_id, main.order_item_id, COALESCE(P.a,0) + COALESCE(C.a,0) - (COALESCE(S.a,0) / main.c) AS price
FROM 
     (((SELECT order_id, order_item_id, count(*) as c FROM main GROUP BY order_id, order_item_id) main LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT amount AS a FROM main WHERE description='Principal') P ON main.order_id =P.order_id AND main.order_item_id = P.order_item_id)  LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT amount AS a FROM main WHERE description='Commission') C ON main.order_id=C.order_id AND main.order_item_id = C.order_item_id)  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     (SELECT amount AS a FROM main WHERE description='Shipping Charges') S ON main.order_id=S.order_id AND main.order_item_id = S.order_item_id
```

above is the sql query which gives a error #1054 - Unknown column 'P.order_id' in 'on clause' can someone help me in correcting to get the desired result as in the image attached.

Comment: In your subquery as p you are not selecting order_id as column so it's said unknown column

Comment: Thanks Ahammed. As this was written by another person and I have little knowledge can help me in correcting the code

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    SELECT main.order_id, main.order_item_id, COALESCE(P.a,0) + COALESCE(C.a,0) - (COALESCE(S.a,0) / main.c) AS price
FROM 
     (((SELECT order_id, order_item_id, count(*) as c FROM main GROUP BY order_id, order_item_id) main LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT main.order_id,main.order_item_id,amount AS a FROM main WHERE description='Principal') P ON main.order_id =P.order_id AND main.order_item_id = P.order_item_id)  LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT main.order_id,main.order_item_id,amount AS a FROM main WHERE description='Commission') C ON main.order_id=C.order_id AND main.order_item_id = C.order_item_id)  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     (SELECT main.order_id,main.order_item_id,amount AS a FROM main WHERE description='Shipping Charges') S ON main.order_id=S.order_id AND main.order_item_id = S.order_item_id
```

Comment: did try that shipping charge is 55 and the order has 2 items so need to be divided by no of items (2) in the order and subtracted on each order item id so we know what is the final received on each order item id so result price would be 184-27.5 & 414-27.5